# C# Process List Cmd Process Original Name

Tags: c#, session, process

I have to run  control.bat file and server.bat files sequentially(Actually 5 files by the way). These are my ERP servers starter programs. Some reason (For example windows updates restarts server) I am trying to compose a windows service to control whether control.bat and server.bat are working or not. If at least one of them doesn't work. It will kill all bat sessions and rerun all with C#. I tried as below.

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (var item in processlist)
{
      Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("control.bat");//there is no processname like control but cmd
      if (pname.Length == 0)
      {
                this.killAll();
                break;

      }       
}
```

But when I control the processlist there is no control.bat or server.bat... But cmd is. Is there a solution finding that cmd file who runs from control.bat, server.bat ...

Comment: `Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("cmd.exe"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the title for a command prompt window with this command

```
title My Running Batch
```

After setting an unique title for the command window it is easy to find if there is a window with that title

```
var list = Process.GetProcesses()
                  .Where(p => p.MainWindowTitle == "My Running Batch");

if(list.Count() == 0)
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't see if a particular batchfile is running that way - the bat file is just a script that the cmd.exe process is executing.

If you initiate the bat file from the code you can *sort* of do this by checking if the process started:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "control.bat";
if (proc.Start())
 {
 //All good!
 }
else
 {
 //Oh no! it's not running!
 }
```

And that way you'll know what's going on.